# How to set domain by word length for bar graph?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a csv which lists words and a corresponding number for each:

wordFile.csv

```
word,count
hello,3
to,4
there,6
```

I am creating a bar graph which has the word name on the x axis and the count is the size of the bar on the y axis. I want to ignore words whose length is < 3. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

        x.domain(self.data.map(function (d) {
                return d.word;
            }
        ));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(self.data, function (d) {
            if(d.word.length > 3) {
                return d.count;
               }
            }
        )]);
```

but this doesn't do the trick.

Is this something that's possible or do I have to edit the csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filter the data before you use it

```
self.data = self.data.filter( d => d.word.length > 3 );

y.domain([0, d3.max(self.data, d => d.count) ]);
```